# Bind an Action to a property of a UserControl in XAML

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a user control which has a button and a dependency property for the action the button is to execute. The page which contains the control sets the action in XAML.

*MyUserControl.cs*

A Button, and dependency property `ButtonAction`, of type `Action`. When the button is clicked it executes the `ButtonAction`.

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

Action Action1

Action Action2

*MainPage.xaml*

Present an instance of `MyUserControl`, with ButtonAction=Action1

**The problem:** The ButtonAction property is not assigned from the XAML

*MyUserControl.cs*

```
    public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public Action ButtonAction {
        get { return (Action)GetValue(ButtonActionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonActionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonActionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonAction", typeof(Action), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,ButtonAction_PropertyChanged));

    private static void ButtonAction_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("ButtonAction_PropertyChanged");
        // Is not called!
    }


    public MyUserControl() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (ButtonAction != null) {
            // Never reaches here!
            ButtonAction();
        }
    }
}
```

*MyUserControl.xaml*

```
    <Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Do The Attached Action!</Button>

</Grid>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
    Action Action1 = (
        () => { Debug.WriteLine("Action1 called"); });

    Action Action2 = (() => { Debug.WriteLine("Action2 called"); });
```

*MainPage.xaml*

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" ButtonAction="{Binding Action1}"/>
</Grid>
```

It *does* work if in the code-behind for MainPage (`MainPage.xaml.cs`) I assign the action in the `Loaded` event.

```
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.myUserControl.ButtonAction = Action1;
    }
```

In this case the PropertyChanged callback in the user control is also called. (This handler is provided only for diagnostic purposes. I can't see how it can be used to support the property in practice).

Comment: What's the DataContext from the MainPage? If its not the page then you have to set ButtonAction="{Binding Action1, ElementName=x:name of the MainPage}"

Comment: The MainPage has no data context - but it works fine like that when the action is assigned in the code-behind. I tried your suggestion (set the name of the page, and ElementName) and it made no difference. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your data binding. The `Action1` in `ButtonAction="{Binding Action1}"` should be a *public property* while you defined it as a private variable.

Also, you cannot just declare a normal property directly in the code behind like that. You will need either a *dependency property*, or more commonly, a *public property* inside a *viewmodel* which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If we go with the second approach, we will need to create a *viewmodel* class like the following with an `Action1` property. Note the `OnPropertyChanged` stuff is just the standard way of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Action _action1;
    public Action Action1
    {
        get { return _action1; }
        set
        {
            _action1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Action1");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And then you just need to assign this to the `DataContext` of your main page.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Action1 = (() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Action1 called");
        });

        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

With these two changes, your `ButtonAction` callback should be firing now. :)

Comment: Both solutions confirmed to work. Very interesting that both INotifyPropertyChanged and DependencyObject work equivalently for data binding in xaml.

Comment: This may seem like common knowledge to WinRT programmers, and I think I already knew, but this question was unanswered, with a bonus, for about 5 days. I suggest that the trouble is that while we use these things in practice we really don't understand, particularly when it comes to the XAML.

Comment: The code for the dependency object solution is:     'class ViewModel : DependencyObject { public Action Action1 { get { return (Action)GetValue(Action1Property); } set { SetValue(Action1Property, value); } } public static readonly DependencyProperty Action1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Action1", typeof(Action), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null)); }`

Comment: That's correct. You might have already known that if you use the dp you will need to modify the xaml slightly by adding `ElementName=MyMainPage` to the binding expression. So something like `ButtonAction="{Binding Action1, ElementName=MyMainPage}"`.

Comment: I didn't need to add the element name with the dp solution. `<local:MyUserControl ButtonAction="{Binding Action1}"/>` works fine.

Comment: Where did you define your Action1 dependency property?

Comment: I defined my `Action1` dependency property in a new class, `ViewModel : DependencyObject`. The complete code is in my previous comment.

Comment: I see. I don't think dependency properties should be defined inside a vm. Also, a vm shouldn't implement DependencyObject. In the current context, a dp Action1 should be defined in MyMainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: That's an improvement! Thanks! In the dp solution I've eliminated the class `ViewModel`, moved the `Action1` dependency property into MainPage.xaml.cs, and changed XAML to `ButtonAction="{Binding Action1, ElementName=MyMainPage}`.

Comment: MainPage.xaml.cs is now: `public sealed partial class MainPage : Page { public MainPage() { this.InitializeComponent(); Action1 = (() => { Debug.WriteLine("Action1 called"); }); } public Action Action1 { get { return (Action)GetValue(Action1Property); } set { SetValue(Action1Property, value); } } public static readonly DependencyProperty Action1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Action1", typeof(Action), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null)); }`